# Background for label dependent on value in cshtml

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, razor

I have following code in my .NET project:

```
<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Number)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status)
        </dd>
```

How can I do background for `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status)`

Actually I have **white** color but I want it when the `model.Status = New` - **green** background, `model.Status = In progress` = **orange** background. Can I dependent it in views?

Comment: That's where CSS `.classes` come in handy... Where's your CSS snippet?

Comment: I have file Content when are bootstrap.css files